# Rendering different template to each host in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Suppose I have a template file, containing, among others, a /24 IP range:

```
...
podCIDR: 192.168.<x>.0/24
...
```

Now, using Ansible, I want to render this template, with a running number from 1 to the number of hosts in my inventory, so that each host will have a different range. The first will have `192.168.1.0/24`, the second `192.168.2.0/24`, etc.

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is it failing? Have you revised the documentation of the [template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the index variable in the *group_vars/all* and use it to create the network

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all
my_index1: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all.index(inventory_hostname) + 1 }}"
podCIDR: "192.168.{{ my_index1 }}.0/24"
```

Then, given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
host_1
host_2
host_3
```

the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_index1
    - debug:
        var: podCIDR
```

gives abridged

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  my_index1: '1'
ok: [host_2] => 
  my_index1: '2'
ok: [host_3] => 
  my_index1: '3'

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  podCIDR: 192.168.1.0/24
ok: [host_2] => 
  podCIDR: 192.168.2.0/24
ok: [host_3] => 
  podCIDR: 192.168.3.0/24
```

See:

- [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)
- [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)
- [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Comment: Thanks. One question: does the `inventory_hostname` must be unique across all the inventory, or is it possible to have 2 hosts with the same name in different groups?

Comment: You're missing: 1) The concept of `inventory_hostname`. See *Special Variables* : *"The inventory name for the ‘current’ host being iterated over in the play*". And 2) [Hosts in multiple groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest//inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-in-multiple-groups). To answer your question. Yes, inventory_hostname is unique. Yes, it is possible to have 2 hosts with the same name in different groups.